# Impossible to remove top marging with CSS (Wordpress Theme)

Tags: css, wordpress, margin

I really tried everything but I still can't remove the top margin of a page (aproxximately 20px). Here is the original page: http://blog.robin.idv.tw/

**(If you inspect the #container div you'll see it has space above but no margin nor padding which displays purple or yellow)**

Here is the modified code:

header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<META name="y_key" content="bd328389f14b8ad2" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="verify-v1" content="/r2Q/NDR8/9+u/mDq9bgYWiS+75+livyGV0i4fww3hg=" />
<title>

<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
<?php if(is_home()) { ?>
 - <?php bloginfo('description'); ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php if(is_single()) { ?>
<?php wp_title(); ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php if(is_404()) { ?>
 - Page Not Found
<?php } ?>
<?php if(is_search()) { ?>
 - Search Results for: <?php echo wp_specialchars($s, 1); ?>
<?php } ?>

</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> RSS Feed" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/tabcontent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

<!-- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ header code ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
<div id="header">
```

index.php:

```
<link href='http://www.robin.idv.tw/images/favicon.ico' rel='shortcut icon'/>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="column">

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ post code ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
<div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<div class="post-top"></div>
<div class="entry">

<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<span class="date"><?php the_time('l, F j, Y'); ?> <?php the_time('G:i'); ?></span>

<div class="info">
<div class="cat">文章分類： <?php the_category(', ') ?></div>
<div class="comments"><?php comments_popup_link('迴響', '1 則迴響', '% 則迴響'); ?></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="content">
```

meyer's reset:

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ */
/* v1.0 | 20080212 */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
/* remember to highlight inserts somehow! */
ins {
    text-decoration: none;
}
del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

style.css:

```
@import "css/reset.css";

body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background: url("images/bg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
}

#container {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* header */
#header {
    width: 980px;
    height: 344px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#header h1, #header h1 a {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 252px;
}

#header h1 {
    margin: 10px 20px 0 0;
}

#header h1 {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#header h1 a {
    background: url('images/logo.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    float: left;
```

generated html:

```
<link href='http://www.robin.idv.tw/images/favicon.ico' rel='shortcut icon'/>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<META name="y_key" content="bd328389f14b8ad2" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="verify-v1" content="/r2Q/NDR8/9+u/mDq9bgYWiS+75+livyGV0i4fww3hg=" />
<title>

Sleex - &quot;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/sleex/wp-content/themes/ocean-of-words/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Sleex RSS Feed" href="http://localhost/sleex/?feed=rss2" />
<link rel="pingback" href="http://localhost/sleex/xmlrpc.php" />
<script src="http://localhost/sleex/wp-content/themes/ocean-of-words/js/tabcontent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://localhost/sleex/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />

<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://localhost/sleex/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<link rel='index' title='Sleex' href='http://localhost/sleex' />
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.0.1" />
    <style type="text/css">.recentcomments a{display:inline !important;padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;}</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

<!-- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ header code ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
<div id="header">

    <div id="logo">

        <h1><a href="http://localhost/sleex/" title="Sleex">Sleex</a></h1>
    </div>

    <div id="pagenav">
        <ul>
            <li class="current_page_item"><a href="http://localhost/sleex">首頁</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://localhost/sleex/?page_id=2" title="About">About</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-4"><a href="http://localhost/sleex/?page_id=4" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>

<li class="page_item page-item-7"><a href="http://localhost/sleex/?page_id=7" title="Submit">Submit</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!--<div id="searchform">-->
        <!--<form method="get" action="http://localhost/sleex/">-->
        <!--<fieldset>-->
        <!--<label>Blog Search</label>-->
        <!--<input type="text" value="" name="s" id="searchinput" />-->

        <!--<input type="submit" value="GO" id="searchbutton" />-->
        <!--</fieldset>-->
        <!--</form>-->
    <!--</div>-->
    <div class="description">
        <p>&quot;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <a href="#">Join the course</a>
    </div>


    <div id="pic">
        <img src="http://localhost/sleex/wp-content/themes/ocean-of-words/images/pic.png"/>
    </div>


</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<!-- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ header code ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->

<div id="column">
```

Comment: Um, we only need to see *either* a live demo page, *and* (for preference) the generated (x)html and the relevant css. The php obscures the information quite badly. Chrome 6.xx on Ubuntu 10.04 doesn't seem to show any extra margin anywhere. Which browser/platform is the problem in?

Comment: @janoChen: you want to shift the #container?

Comment: @David Thomas I added the generated html. The page I provide has almost the same structure and the same problem.

Comment: @Michael Mao what do yo mean I want to shift #container?

Comment: @janoChen, he's trying to work out which `div` has the extra margin-top that you want to remove, and suggests the `div` with an `id` of `container` that seems to contain your page.

Comment: @David Thomas the div #container has margin and padding 0

Comment: @janoChen Your page is rendering in quirk mode because of the favicon `link` tag appearing before the `doctype` (not shown in the code you gave here)

Comment: @Yi Jiang hey thanks you saved my day why didn't you answer as a question so that I can vote your answer

Answer (score 0):

as @YiJuang said. I removed it as a local test and the spacing went away